# How to show that a limit exists without using an epsilon-delta proof or a graph

Tags: limits

Suppose I'm trying to show that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}x^2=4.$$ Obviously this limit exits, but suppose I didn't know that it did. Is there a way I can show that the limit exists without using an epsilon-delta proof or a graph? Would say $\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}x^2=(2)^2=4$ be enough to say that the limit exists or could I say that since $x^2$ is continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$ then the limit as $x$ approaches $2$ eixsts?

Comment: If you already have proved that polynomials are continuous obviously you know not only that the limit exists, but also that its value is $2^2=4$.

Comment: you can use that $$x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2)$$   and that $$\lim_{x\to 2}(x-2)(x+2)=0$$

Comment: The $\epsilon-\delta$ proof method is a rigorous _definition_ for limit, so I don't think you can really avoid it for a rigorous proof. Any method you use would have it hidden subtly within it.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas You can avoid it by using other theorems that use it (thus, you implicitly use $\epsilon-\delta$, but you avoid using it as a proof method.

Comment: The $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of limits is not a practical method to evaluate limits. Limits are almost always evaluated using theorems meant to evaluate limits (algebra of limits, squeeze theorem, substitution, L'Hospital's Rule, Taylor expansions etc) combined with a certain set of standard limits. The limit in question is very easy and uses two key ideas: the standard limit $\lim_{x\to a} x=a$ (proved easily via definition) and the product rule of limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know:

1. That $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$
2. The theorem:

   > $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=f(a)$$

then sure, you can say $$\lim_{x\to 2} x^2=2^2.$$

But if you don't yet know points $1$ and $2$, then you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

using epsilon-delta proof method is the way you define limit so for not using it you will have to use a method that use it in the background. In that case, a function is continuous at $a$ iff $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$, and you know that $x^2$ is continuous at $(-\infty,\infty)$ so you can say that for $f(x)=x^2$ you have $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=2^2=4$, but if you want to show that $x^2$ is continuous over $(-\infty,\infty)$ you will have to use the epsilon-delta proof